# How to cancel 'Ready to Publish'

Tags: android, google-play-console

Google has reviewed and it's 'Ready to Publish' but I don't want to publish this update. Is there a way to cancel this without publishing?

If I try to turn off 'managed publishing' it says the update would be published!!

If I try to upload a new version, it says the same thing, that the updates in 'Ready to publish' would be published.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cancel the old version, you can upload a new one but make sure the version code is at least one number up and then release the version that you want to publish